# Records fetched are 5000 but too many DML error showing off

Tags: batch, integration

I am doing an inbound Integration,where I am using HTTPGet method and inserting those records in Salesforce.
Below is the code.
listjsonFormatClass is the list of the Wrapper Class where i am sending the response and deserializing it.
accountList is the list of Accounts which I am getting in the Start method of the batch after running this query:

```
select id,CustomerId__c,name,lastmodifieddate from Account
```

I am using this batchclass with implementing the **Database.Allowscallouts** as well.

```
 for(jsonFormatClass jsonFormatClassObject : listjsonFormatClass){
                    for(Account accObject : accountList){
                        if(accObject.TestId__c!= String.ValueOf(jsonFormatClassObject.testID)){
                            accountObj = new Account();
                            accountObj.TestId__c= String.ValueOf(jsonFormatClassObject.testID);
                            accountObj.Name = jsonFormatClassObject.Name;
                            accountToBeInsertedList.add(accountObj);                        
                        }
                        else{
                             accountObj = new Account();
                            accountObj.TestId__c= String.ValueOf(jsonFormatClassObject.testID);
                            accountObj.Name = jsonFormatClassObject.Name;
                            accountToBeUpdatedList.add(accountObj);
                        }
                    }
                }
insert accountToBeInsertedList;
```

Comment: can you paste the error here?

Comment: Error in debug  - Too many DML rows: 10001

Comment: Have you tried reducing the batch scope size from the default of 200 to say 20? Perhaps your insert is causing trigger and other logic to fire that is consuming DML statements. The general idea is that while `start` might return a large number of records, each `execute` can be set to process a small number of records per invocation.

Comment: This is a new sandbox. No other logic is present.This is the only batch class in the whole sandbox. Its my own developer sandbox. I have tried to do 20,10,1 every possible scope.I have tried to do this without the batch as well I am facing the same error there too.

Comment: How many records are there in listjsonFormatClass list and accountList?

Comment: @Aditya, The problem is, you are running using nested for loops. Lets say  `listjsonFormatClass` has 5000 records and `accountList` has 3 records. So for each `jsonFormatClassObject`, total of three accounts will be created, so the final total will be `5000 * 3` i.e. 15000. If I am not wrong you want only one account per `jsonFormatClassObject`.

Comment: @Rahul ,yes you are correct. Could you help me in resolving that.ListjsonFormatClass has 5000 records and accountlist has 12 records.

Comment: @Aditya I have written the sample code in answer plz check.

Comment: @Rahul , I have do one more thing over here.Added a question in the below url.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267760/invalid-date-time

Need to check the lastmodifiedDate of the accounts to be inserted with the Date value of the header which is being sent in the jsonResponse.
Format - Mon, 01 Jul 2019 10:20:06 GMT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of scenarios, you can always use maps. I am writing some pseudo code below.

```
// After you query records, create a map of accounts by TestId__c
Map<String,Account> accountMap = new Map<String, Account>();
for(Account accountObj: accountList){
    accountMap.put(accountObj.TestId__c, accountObj); // assuming testid being unique for each account.
}
```

Then you need to iterate over the list you getting from the response.

```
for(jsonFormatClass jsonFormatClassObject : listjsonFormatClass){
    String testIdStr = String.ValueOf(jsonFormatClassObject.testID);
    Account accountObj;
    // if its existing account, it make sense to update it instead of creating new.
    if(accountMap.containsKey(testIdStr)){
        accountObj = accountMap.get(testIdStr);
        accountObj.TestId__c= String.ValueOf(jsonFormatClassObject.testID);
        accountObj.Name = jsonFormatClassObject.Name;
        accountToBeInsertedList.add(accountObj);         
    } else {
        // create new account.
        accountObj = new Account();
        accountObj.TestId__c= String.ValueOf(testIdStr);
        accountObj.Name = jsonFormatClassObject.Name;
        accountToBeUpdatedList.add(accountObj);
    }
}
// instead of inserting new you can update existing. So I would recommend to use Upsert.
upsert newAccounts;
```

To avoid governor limits and to write an optimized code you can learn more about the best practices [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code). As a beginner, this will be really helpful for you.

Happy coding!!

Comment: Hi @Rahul, Thanks for your help.