# Invalid Date Time

Tags: apex, integration, datetime

While trying to retrieve the headers from an integration response, I am getting a Datetime value in String format in the Header.

Format - Mon, 01 Jul 2019 10:20:06 GMT
I need to compare this with the lastmodifieddate of Account.

Code  :

```
        String strDate = headers.get('Date');
        DateTime lastmodified = DateTime.valueOfGmt(strDate);
        String utcDt = lastmodified.format('yyyy-mm-dd', 'UTC');
        system.debug('!===lastmodified : '+lastmodified);
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have used the datetime.format,datetimeGmtformat,datetime,valueof,DateTime.valueOfGmt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by formatting lastmodifieddate to String.

Here is the example:

```
Datetime x = Datetime.now();
String s = x.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT';
system.debug(s); // Mon, 01 Jul 2019 10:39:14 GMT
```

After that you can compare the header value.

Links to documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Comment: I don't think this is going to work.
It is the extension of this  .
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267745/records-fetched-are-5000-but-too-many-dml-error-showing-off
Added a comment over in that URL as well.

Comment: ```Datetime account_lastModifiedDate = someAccount.LastModifiedDate;
system.assertEquals(header_lastModifiedDate, account_lastModifiedDate.formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT');```

@Aditya
That's not true, in the case like this it's going to work. What you are trying to do is convert string to datetime. In cintrast, I am converting datetime (lastmodifieddate of account) to string and comparing it to the header string.

Comment: It seems to work . Thanks